# How to find all files with the same basename within an IF statement using Unix

Tags: unix, if-statement

In the code below, I have an if statement attempting to exit the program if the user inputs 'safe_rm' as an argument. However it does not account for files with  the same name in other directories. How can I improve the code so it does?

```
for i in $*
 do
  if [[  'safe_rm' = $i ]]
  then
   echo "Attempting to delete safe_rm - operation aborted"
  exit
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Search if `safe_rm` exists in the argument using `grep`.

The following code works for me and accounts for filenames with `safe_rm` in other directories too:

```
for i in $*
 do
  if echo $i | grep -q 'safe_rm'
  then
   echo "Attempting to delete safe_rm - operation aborted"
  exit
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

## useing basename command

```
for i in $*
do
    if [[  'safe_rm' = $(basename $i) ]]
    then
       echo "Attempting to delete safe_rm - operation aborted"
       exit
     fi
done
```